# Let $f$ satisfy $f(mr)<f(r)$ for all $m,r\in \mathbb N$. Is $f(k)$ decreasing for all large $k$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions, reference-request

Consider the question

> Let $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ satisfy $f(mr)<f(r)$ for all $m,r\in \mathbb N$, $m>1$. Is $f(k)$ decreasing for all $k>k_0$ for some $k_0$?

The answer is clearly no as we have the following counterexample
$$f(n)=\begin{cases}
1/n & \text{when $n$ is even}\\
2/n & \text{when $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}$$
where $f$ is increasing at all even values of $n$.

Now, my question is whether there are any extra (minimal) assumptions that we can put on $f(k)$ to make it decreasing for large $k$? Or rather what non-trivial conditions can be imposed on $f$ to make it decreasing?

I feel like I may have seen a similar problem before (in some Olympiad question probably) but I really don't remember where. And, a google search doesn't yield anything useful. Please let me know if anyone has seen this problem before or has any idea how to handle it.

---

I understand that given this setup, $f$ does not have any constraints at the primes except the upper bound $f(p)<f(1)$. But, I must point out that this does not imply we can set any values at the primes since we also need to make sure that $f$ at the multiples of these primes don't clash.

Comment: Is $m$ required to be $> 1$? Otherwise, we have $f(1 \times r) < f(r)$

Comment: Your condition does not restrict values at primes.

Comment: @VezenBU thanks, I made the edit!

Comment: I think @coffeemath's point is very important! For any increasing sequence of primes $p_1, p_2, \ldots$, the values $f(p_i)$ have no constraints at all.

Comment: @VezenBU please check my edit

Comment: I think the problem still exists. For any $k_0$, you can find two primes $k_0 < p_1 < p_2$ and set $f(p_1) < f(p_2)$.